# ¿Cómo arreglo este error de compilación?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Me aparece este error:

> Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments [build_d9ihmwfxbjo807djs03q96gki$_run_closure1@2e2739b0] on root project 'Red Social TravelNet' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

No se como solucionarlo.
He probado a añadir líneas que otros usuarios han puesto en preguntas similares, pero no he conseguido nada, he intentado deshabilitar gradle y tampoco consigo solucionarlo. Esta es mi ultima opción o sino probare a reinstalar todo desde cero.
Este es mi `build.gradle(:app)`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.redsystem.redsocialtravelnet"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.1'                
    implementation 'com.google.android/material:material:1.1.0'     
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'   
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.5'       
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'           
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'               
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'       
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'    
}
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Y también dejo el `build.gradle(RedSocialTravelNet)`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 32
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al error:

> Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments

debes asegurar que en tu archivo `build.gradle` que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto se tenga definido como primera linea:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

asegura tener esta linea y vuelve a construir el proyecto.